# remove letters from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
['PFRMAT,RR', 'TARGET,', 'AUTHOR,5014-2892-3830', 'MODEL,1', 'TGAHPAFKYLAQTSGKEPTWNFWKYLVAPDGKVVGAWDPTVSVEEVRPQI', 'TALVR', '3,9', '3,16', '3,17', '3,18', '3,21', '3,25', '3,26', '3,27', '3,28', '3,29', '3,30']
```

How can I remove the string letters, so the list becomes `['3,9','3,16','3,17','3,18']`
I don't want to use a function that removes the first 6 elements like `del` as the amount of string of letters at the start isn't a fixed amount

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[elem for elem in my_list if not any(c.isalpha() for c in elem)]
```

takes `my_list` and returns a new list with all elements that have no letters in it. It is a list comprehension (thanks @Lattyware) returning a new list, so you probably want to return it back to `my_list`:

```
my_list = [elem for elem in my_list if not any(c.isalpha() for c in elem)]
```

Comment: +1. As a note, this is a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Comment: This just gives me an empty list

Comment: I get this list: `['3,9', '3,16', '3,17', '3,18', '3,21', '3,25', '3,26', '3,27', '3,28', '3,29', '3,30']`